# python telegram bot button

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

i'm trying to write a telegram bot. i design 2 button in start handler. now i want to tell bot if user choose first button you should do sth. how can i write this code?
this is my code:

```
async def start_handler(update: Update, context:ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> int:
    reply_keyboard=[["1.docx to pdf"],["2.pdf to office"]]
    await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id,
                                    text="Hi!\n"
                                    "Wellcome to Convert.Bot\n"
                                    "Tell me how can i help you by choosing a button",
                                    reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard=reply_keyboard,
                                                                     one_time_keyboard=True,),
                                    reply_to_message_id=update.effective_message.id
                                        )
    return WORK

async def work_handler(update: Update, context:ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> int:
    if "1" in update.effective_message.text:
        print('123')
```

print('123') didn't work.
i know start handler should return some function and i should use if order, but i don't know the if statement.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.